# Compiz not showing complete windows

Tags: 11.04, compiz, unity-2d

When i work with compiz as windows manager, my windows are not complete (title bar is missing and white - no longer colored).

I cannot move the windos either.  When Y go back to metacity no problems. I had to install compiz fusion icon for do this change, and I work no longer with unity-2d.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sounds like you solved your problem, congrats! You now need to mark your answer as The Answer. It's an important part of the AskUbuntu community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment i found this solution.  First op all i reset compiz with :

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
```

and unity reset to:

```
unity --reset
```

I found this at www.webupd8.org.  The windows are normal now.  Compiz is my windows manager.  The colour is back and i can move the windows.